# How Do I Prevent copyValuesToRange from Overwriting Destination with Blank or Null Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, null, copy, range

For the most part, using copyValuesToRange works very well (99.9% of the time) in a function with the following statements:

```
let source = ss.getSheetByName("Update List");
let destination = ss.getSheetByName("Power Level");
source.getRange('TIER1DescImport').copyValuesToRange(destination, 12, 12, 6, 29); // 'PowerLevel'!L6:L29
```

The source is on a sheet "Update List" with a named data range "TIER1DescImport". The imported data is from a separate Google Sheet file using IMPORTRANGE.

ONCE, the destination range was entirely overwritten with empty or blank cells. How do I prevent this from happening again? I don't know why this occurred. The source range seemed fine. After closing the Google sheet and opening it 30 minutes later, everything was working properly again.

Is there a way of determining if the source range is okay, and if so, proceed with copyValuesToRange?

I'm a novice using Apps Script. I didn't know how to debug this issue. The only thing that worked was closing the files and coming back to it later. After that, it all seemed to be working again. I don't know why the destination was overwritten with blank or empty data but I'd like to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example [mcve]

Comment: I wish I could provide a reproducible example. The code works but one time, it didn't. I'm seeking a way to prevent it from overwriting the entire destination range with blank/empty/null data if there ever was a problem with the source range. Basically, asking if there is a way to check if there is valid data in the source range before copying it to the destination range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test whether the source range has a meaningful amount of data with something like this:

```
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Power Level');
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Update List');
  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange('TIER1DescImport');
  if (sourceRange.getDisplayValues.join('').length > 10) {
    sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(targetSheet, 12, 12, 6, 29);
    // ...or: sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange('L6'));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question and providing a solution. This is helpful.